# Ternary operator in Java always returns null

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot

I don't have much experience with Java, but I use ternary operators in C#, and it's such a trivial thing that I don't think about it when I use it.

Recently I started a Spring Boot project, and I have something like this:

```
dto.setProfilePhoto(dao.getProfilePhoto() != null ? dao.getProfilePhoto() : "images/default-img.png");
```

but the profile photo always came back null.
Then I turned on debugger mode, and evaluated some expressions and this totally confused me...

Expression: boolean t = true ? true : false; ---> null

Expression: boolean t = 10 > 2 ? true : false; ---> null

Why do I get null values for these expressions?

Edit: Here are the getter and setter

```
public String getProfilePhoto() {
    return ProfilePhoto;
}

public void setProfilePhoto(String profilePhoto) {
    ProfilePhoto = profilePhoto;
}
```

Comment: Because your debugger isn't analyzing the correct code; restart the IDE and try again.

Comment: That ternary operator cannot evaluate to `null`, so if `dto.profilePhoto` is `null` after that statement, then the `setProfilePhoto()` method is not working. Since we can't see that method, we can't help with that. Please [create a Minimal, **Reproducible** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for further help.

Comment: You get `null` in these expressions because they are assignments that return nothing. Either do `boolean t = true ? true : false; return t;`,  or better and shorter  `true ? true : false`.

Comment: @Andreas See getter and setter above.

Comment: @howlger Or even better and shorter, true.

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned the implementation of `dao.getProfilePhoto()` e.g. it might be advancing to `null` in the second call. You can try it as follows:

```
String profilePhoto = dao.getProfilePhoto();
dto.setProfilePhoto(profilePhoto != null ? profilePhoto : "images/default-img.png");
```

It is not only efficient but also makes it agnostic of the implementation of `dao.getProfilePhoto()`.